# Running a python script from a command line in Windows

Tags: python

I'm currently following the book, "Learning Python The Hard Way" and I am stuck trying to make a script run from the command line.

I have saved this text:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

as ex13.py in my Python folder. When I try to run it from cmd, it comes up with this error:

```
"File "<stdin>", line 1
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
          ^
```

Can you explain what this means and how I can fix it?
Sorry for being a noob :)

Answer (score 7):

It *looks* like you are typing the line

```
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

into the python interpreter.  You are supposed to type that at the `cmd` prompt.

Comment: I just tried that and it says this "python: can't open file 'ex13.py': [Errno 2] because there is no such file or directory."

Comment: James: then you need to `cd` to the directory containing the script, or use the full pathname.