# How To Run A Python File From Windows Command Line

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, command-line, command-prompt

I'm sorry if this question is simple but i'm new to Python and have searched around but not found my answer.

Here it is:

How do I run a .py file from the Python interpreter? I'd like to run this file: C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Python\Python-Test.py

So far, I've:

- Downloaded Active Python (http://www.activestate.com/activepython).
- Set the PATH to open the interpreter from the Windows Command Line. The Python interpreter works fine, allowing me to print simple calculations.

Thanks for your time,

Dan.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html

Comment: Did you bother with searching first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402411/running-a-python-script-from-a-command-line-in-windows?rq=1

Comment: Type `python C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Python\Python-Test.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know

> How do I run a .py file from the Python interpreter?

this will work

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Desktop\\Python")
import Python-Test
```

But your question says from the command line, which has been answered in the comments.

Comment: Consider ticking a answer if it helped